# why i am not able to install all the dependencies in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, package, npm-install

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhueQ.jpg)I tried running all the commands including npx create-react-app npm create-react-app npm install npm clear cache --f everything.
still i am not able to install all the dependencies in my package json

Comment: npx create-react-app <app-name> ... cd  <app-name> ... npm start

Comment: @RohanAgarwal i have already tried this. Its still not working

Comment: Try yarn install

Comment: @Darvesh This is also asking for fund. Can you tell me why these packages are not getting installed and asking for fund

Comment: run the following command if you need to create package.json.  npx create-react-app my-app --use-npm.

Comment: It's asking for donations. Ignore those. It won't cause any problem.

Comment: Read this to know more about how to create app with create-react-app  https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: sure i am trying @Darvesh

Answer (score 0):

The fact that a package is asking for funding should not affect your installation. It simply means that the author(s) is/are looking for financial support to continue their work.

To create a new installation and avoid possible issues - go to a new directory and type the following on your command prompt:-

```
npx create-react-app todo1
```

Then, you need to navigate to the folder of your newly created app, "todo1" by running the following:

```
cd todo1
```

Finally to run the app, type the following:

```
npm start
```

Comment: Can you please type `ls` or `dir` and share the contents of the folder

Comment: https://imgur.com/wGcSrBG https://imgur.com/j9VCovM

Comment: Take a look at this thread, similar problem to the one you're facing, with q few possible solutions. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088

Answer (score 0):

First I want to say your commands are not clear and those are not separated. I assume you need to create react app with npm package manager.

If you run `npx create-react-app todo1` you will create a react app with yarn dependency manager.

If you need to use npm dependency manager use the following command

```
npx create-react-app todo1 --use-npm
```

Then check the root directory. it should have the `package.json` file with necessary initial dependencies.

Comment: hey i am sorry for that. but yeah i have tried all the commands that i have been using bt none of them is working . I even tried this method too still it is showing the same error                                    https://imgur.com/MR0IxMy

Comment: If you run the above command please go to the todo1 folder (cd todo1) and then run npm start. Seems you are still in the pic folder.

Comment: https://imgur.com/j9VCovM https://imgur.com/wGcSrBG   i tried that it is showing start script is missing